I have used aws codemod to convert a lambda from using v2 to v3 of the sdk, however the lambda still cannot find the aws-sdk
I have used the following command to convert my index.js file:
npx aws-sdk-js-codemod -tv2-to-v3 filepath/index.js
My new file is now:
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
 
const { Connect } = require("@aws-sdk/client-connect");
 
const proxy = require("proxy-agent");
const { TIME_FRAME, PROXY_URL } = process.env;
// JS SDK v3 does not support global configuration.
// Codemod has attempted to pass values to each service client in this file.
// You may need to update clients outside of this file, if they use global config.
AWS.config.update({
    // The transformation for httpOptions is not implemented.
    // Refer to UPGRADING.md on aws-sdk-js-v3 for changes needed.
    // Please create/upvote feature request on aws-sdk-js-codemod for httpOptions.
    httpOptions: {
        agent: proxy(PROXY_URL),
    },
});
const padLeft = (num) => (num < 10 ? `0${num}` : num);
const fixMinutes = (num) => Math.floor(num / 5) * 5;
const formatDate = (y, mon, d, h, m) => `${y}-${mon}-${d}T${h}:${m}`;
const extractDate = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const minute = fixMinutes(now.getMinutes());
    return {
        year: now.getFullYear(),
        month: padLeft(now.getMonth() + 1),
        day: padLeft(now.getDate()),
        hour: padLeft(now.getHours()),
        minute: padLeft(minute),
    };
};
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const { ARN } = event["Details"]["ContactData"]["Queue"];
    const cleanedIds = ARN.split("instance/")[1].split("/queue/");
    const InstanceId = cleanedIds[0];
    const QueueId = cleanedIds[1];
    const connect = new Connect({
        // The key apiVersion is no longer supported in v3, and can be removed.
        // @deprecated The client uses the "latest" apiVersion.
        apiVersion: "2017-08-08",
 
        // The transformation for httpOptions is not implemented.
        // Refer to UPGRADING.md on aws-sdk-js-v3 for changes needed.
        // Please create/upvote feature request on aws-sdk-js-codemod for httpOptions.
        httpOptions: {
            agent: proxy(PROXY_URL),
        },
    });
    const { year, month, day, hour, minute } = extractDate();
    const formattedEndDateTime = formatDate(year, month, day, hour, minute);
    const formattedStartDateTime = formatDate(year, month, day, hour, "00");
    const EndTime = new Date(formattedEndDateTime);
    const StartTime = new Date(formattedStartDateTime);
    StartTime.setMinutes(minute - TIME_FRAME);
    const params = {
        EndTime,
        StartTime,
        InstanceId,
        MaxResults: 10,
        Filters: {
            Channels: ["VOICE"],
            Queues: [QueueId],
        },
        HistoricalMetrics: [
            {
            Name: "QUEUE_ANSWER_TIME",
            Statistic: "AVG",
            Unit: "SECONDS",
            },
        ],
    };
    const { MetricResults } = await connect.getMetricData(params);
    const { Collections } = MetricResults[0];
    let waitTime = 15;
    if (Collections.length !== 0) {
    waitTime = Math.ceil(Collections[0].Value / 60);
    }
    return callback(null, {
    waitTime,
    });
};


However the lambda is still producing the following error:
"Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack"
Have tried using the codemod to automatically convert my file to the new version. Was expecting the lambda to pass without issue, however it continues to error
